# How to reuse a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

Is there any way to create a `ViewController` which does all the job I need and manages all the views and add another `UIViewController` to my `Storyboard` which extends the first `UIViewController` without the need of setup the layout again?
For example:

1. I create `MyMapController` which has a map inside and it loads the map and all the other stuff I need
2. I create a new `UIViewController` called for example `ToiletsMapController` which extends `MyMapController` and I override some methods I need.
3. I add a `UIViewController` in my storyboard and I set his custom class as `ToiletsMapController`.

Is it possible? If so where I can create `MyMapController`? Is it better to use a separate xib file?

**Update**:
It would be better if I can include it in a `Storyboard` but other solutions are welcome, I am using Objective-C.

Comment: Can it be programmatically? And in what language for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIViewController` subclass called `BaseViewController`. In the `viewDidLoad` of this class, add all your subviews to the view. Make your other viewcontrollers subclass this `BaseViewController` and your added views will be inherited there.

After that you can customize it as you wish. Such as in your maps example, the baseviewcontroller will only contain the map object which you can refer in your child class and add annotations to.

Comment: I thought about this solution but the layout is quite complicated and add all the views manually is going to be a long task, is there a way to do it using a xib file or something similar?

Comment: as far as I know, components added to the interface builder are only visible on that particular screen and cannot be viewed in any other. and you only have to add the views manually once in the base class

Comment: So there is no way to do what i want?